# pulling data from two different tables with common row elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

```
Table a:
name  qty
a     10
b     20
c     30 
d     40

and table b
name qty
a     10
b     20
d     20
e     60.
```

I want to merge there two tables and create a new table like this

```
name    qty
 a       20
 b       40
 c       30 
 d       60  
 e       60
```

The objective is to add the values if there is have the same value in name or else  just append the values in table two to table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support `full outer join`.  Here is a method using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select name, sum(qty) as qty
from ((select name, qty from a) union all
      (select name, qty from b)
     ) ab
group by name;
```

Comment: I think the syntax is wrong. Could you please check it?

Comment: @Morpheus . . . The syntax looks correct to me.  Why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a full outer join, just execute a left outer join (gives all the rows of Table A with all matching rows of Table B or NULL) and a right outer join where Table A is NULL (gives all the rows of Table B that have no match in Table A -- matches are already provided in first query).

In the first query, there will always be a Qty value from Table A with either a Qty value or NULL from Table B. In the second query, there will only be a Qty value from Table B.

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8089a/2/0)</kbd> results.

```
select  a.Name, a.Qty + IsNull( b.Qty, 0 ) as Qty
from    @TableA a
left outer join @TableB b
    on  b.Name = a.Name
union all
select  b.Name, b.Qty
from    @TableA a
right outer join @TableB b
    on  b.Name = a.Name
where   a.Name is null;
```

You may use `union` or `union all` with the same results. Since there is less processing required with `union all`, that's what I chose.